# How to use dynamic nested object key in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript

Let's say I have a generic type like bellow

```
type GeneratePipeline<T = any> = {
        localField: keyof T;
    }
```

and interface User

```
interface User {
  email : string,
  password : string,
  generalInfo : {
    firstName: string
    lastName : string
    departmentId : string
  }
}
```

then I Create a type for GeneratePipeline by User

```
const UserPipeLine :GeneratePipeline<User>  = {
  localField : "generalInfo.departmentId"
}
```

Typescript throws an error at the line "generalInfo.departmentId".

How can I solve this issue? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for answer, but that's not my issue

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBKwDGBXKBnASwDdgBpYRAeQDMAeAFUoCMArOUGYAOwBM84IrLDAB8cALxwA3gCg4cANr1yiOAS5wA1hQjU4jVnABkcABR4YUdQHM4AHzhdsAWybAoASgC6ALjnz9ZhYlFS92EE5efgBDLkQFMIB+OAADABIpZQoAXxS4PwDA1hCKMI5uPgEhTBh-QuT0zJVc+1SMrMRsgDoMjBx8YjIKGgYgksQvEVy6gJ82ppyUgG4ZbIVtRF0ithNzSxtWp1d3bxWZJBQ4AHFud2jOAAUCFAAbdWAGcMjKwRZhMUkskKLwgmGiLwAYgRgC8eHM+rhCCQVCN6CJVjMZOpOFBqNFMKgAKp4dzSfzAZzRAgvfJwCxWLjWAA0-jA0TweAA7tAeLT6TYWfJrLcoOCAJJcagQWlAgLUAj4GAAOWizmAc35jJmL3ZytVqA1+y1hR4wDZsDVXBgYt5hoZ1n82QxMhewHgxPcTxQABl3vkblw7o9njD3rQPVAAWT5CCwZDobC5gByYWB0UvCVSrqm80wS3WnhJ1ZAA

Answer (score 0):

You can create another interface for `generalInfo` and use it in the UserPipeLine.

```
interface GeneralInfo {
  firstName: string
  lastName : string
  departmentId : string
}

interface User {
  email : string,
  password : string,
  generalInfo: GeneralInfo
}

const UserPipeLine :GeneratePipeline<User & GeneralInfo>  = {
  localField : "departmentId"
}
```

Comment: Hi, I need that field have value generalInfo.departmentId because I will put that object into another parser function.